# Injecting concrete instance into Ninject resolver

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-injection, ninject, ninject-extensions

Its easy enough using NInject to establish dependency injection using interfaces.

So for example say I have a class like

```
public class WindowManagerService : IWindowManager 
{
    public WindowManagerService(ILogger logger) { }
}
```

It's easy to do something like this:

```
public class NinjectModuleLoader : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        this.Bind<IWindowManager>().To<WindowManagerService>().InSingletonScope();
    }
}
```

and successfully configure the dependency injection.

However the problem I run into is when I need to provide a concrete instance of a class into the constructor such as the following example:

```
public class ObservableLogger : ILogger
{
    public ObservableLogger(Dispatcher dispatcher) { }
}
```

In the above example I require the ability to pass in a concrete implementation of the dispatcher as I cannot use DI to establish this link and must reference the application wide `Dispatcher` instance.

Essentially what I wish to be able to do is something like this:

```
this.Bind<ILogger>().To(new ObservableLogger(Dispatcher)).InSingletonScope();
```

So how does one provide concrete implementations of dependencies to the NInject dependency manager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a factory method:

```
this.Bind<ILogger>().ToMethod(context => new ObservableLogger(Dispatcher));
```

...or create your own custom provider as explained in the docs: https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Providers,-Factory-Methods-and-the-Activation-Context

There is also the `ToConstant` and `ToConstructor` methods:

```
this.Bind<ILogger>().ToConstant(new ObservableLogger(Dispatcher));
```

Please refer to [this blog post](https://lukewickstead.wordpress.com/2013/02/09/howto-ninject-part-2-advanced-features/) for more information.